# When to use CRYPT_ACQUIRE_COMPARE_KEY_FLAG

Tags: c++, c, winapi, cryptography

I'm unable to find an explanation or recommendation for when you should specify the `CRYPT_ACQUIRE_COMPARE_KEY_FLAG` flag in calls to [`CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379885(v=vs.85).aspx). I can't come up with an example of where this would be necessary.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Perhaps it's a function of a specific CSP?

Comment: I've formatted the code a bit and added the C and C++ language tags, mainly to broaden the visibility of the question. It's a native API after all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ok, I like the tags and reviewed the page source to see what you did with the formatting.

Comment: This relates to your question: [What does NTE_BAD_PUBLIC_KEY really mean?](https://marc.info/?l=ms-cryptoapi&m=104915333309896&w=2)